# tar + gz files from folder as is without to put inside all sub folder

Tags: linux, tar, archive

we want to tar.gz all the following jars files

```
2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/super-csv-2.2.0.jar
2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/univocity-parsers-2.2.1.jar
2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar
2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/xmlenc-0.52.jar
2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/xz-1.0.jar
2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/zookeeper-3.4.6.2.6.4.0-91.jar
```

so I do the following

```
cd /var/tmp
tar -czvf archive.tar.gz /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars
```

but when I do

```
tar xvf archive.tar.gz
```

we get the usr folder

```
usr
```

while the expected results should be only the jars as ( without the sub folders )

```
    super-csv-2.2.0.jar
    univocity-parsers-2.2.1.jar
    validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
    xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar
    xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
    jxmlenc-0.52.jar
    xz-1.0.jar
    zookeeper-3.4.6.2.6.4.0-91.jar
```

what is wrong with my syntax

```
 cd /var/tmp
 tar -czvf archive.tar.gz /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-C` option to let tar `chdir` into the directory before starting to archive the files:

```
tar -czf archive.tar.gz -C /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars .
```

Do not forget the dot as last argument

Note that the first argument after the `f` argument is the file name to output the archive to and the following option `-C` takes the directory name as argument (where tar `chdir`s to)  and then the dot is the directory to start archiving.

Comment: it create the "-C" file

Comment: the problem is that - after tar xvf   archive.tar.gz , we see also the "-c" file and the file itself  archive.tar.gz

Comment: You do not get it, but if your local `tar` implementation really behaves the way you claim, you need to throw it away as it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

`tar` stores the full path passed on the command line.

If you want just the `2.6.4.0-91` directory, simple `cd` into it *before* calling `tar`.

Please keep in mind that in this case, you should *specify* where you want the archive to end with the `-C` option.

As an example, say you are in `/home/user/`:

```
cd /usr/hdp/
tar -czvf -C /home/user/archive.tar.gz 2.6.4.0-91/spark2/jars/
```

Comment: This creates a file named -C